# Symfony 5 - How to render page error 404 instead of the Symfony Exception page?

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

I'm trying to visualize an error 404 that isn't the Symfony Exception page.

Even when the site is in production mode, it doesn't render the default 404 error page:

[image]

I've tried to look into the directories in the vendor: in the `http-kernel`, `twig-bundle`, `twig-bridge`, `twig` and `error-handler`, to try and change something, anything, but without success.
I've tried to look into the `debug.yaml` in the `config` directory, but nothing.

I've made some research, but it show only how to personalize the 404 error page, but that's not the current issue.

I don't know what I have to change to render even just the default error page.

**EDIT - 17 May 2022**

I have checked with the command `php bin/console about` on the VSCode teminal and here the result:

```
λ php bin/console about
 -------------------- --------------------------------- 
  Symfony
 -------------------- --------------------------------- 
  Version              5.4.6
  Long-Term Support    Yes
  End of maintenance   11/2024 (in +928 days)
  End of life          11/2025 (in +1293 days)
 -------------------- --------------------------------- 
  Kernel
 -------------------- --------------------------------- 
  Type                 App\Kernel
  Environment          prod
  Debug                false
  Charset              UTF-8
  Cache directory      ./var/cache/prod (7.1 MiB)
  Build directory      ./var/cache/prod (7.1 MiB)
  Log directory        ./var/log (47.5 MiB)
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  PHP
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  Version              7.4.9
  Architecture         64 bits
  Intl locale          en_GB
  Timezone             UTC (2022-05-17T12:49:36+00:00)
  OPcache              false
  APCu                 false
  Xdebug               false
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
```

I've also send the command `composer dump-end prod` and it created the file `.env.local.php`, within the key `APP_ENV=prod`.

But I get the same Symfony Exection error page.

Comment: How do you check if symfony runs at prod environment?

Comment: On the `.env` file, I have to change the `APP_ENV` key from `dev` to `prod`

Comment: If you see this red error, Symfony think you are not in prod environment. Maybe you have a .env.local who override your .env ? or variables environment ?

Comment: Did you try clearing the Symfony cache?

Comment: I did cleaned the Symfony cache but didn't changed anything

Comment: I don't have a `.env.local`. I have a `.env.test` but never really used it. Every variable environment used has been from `.env`

Answer (score 1):

I was using the `web-server-bundle` to launch my server (`php bin/console server:run`).

When I tried to use a different command to start the local server (`php -S localhost:8000 -t public/`), the page 404 worked.